# Difference between various iOS versions from iPhone OS 2.0 to iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to know what are the differences between the different iOS versions, from iPhone OS 2.0 to iOS 6.0 from a development prospective. I would like to develop a universal application which should be run on all iOS devices.

Comment: Apple doesn't let developers distribute application built with iOS SDK older than 4.3 anymore.

Comment: Apple no longer accepts apps compatible with any OS below 3.0. Soon they may no longer provide tools to develop for both the latest iOS and anything below OS 4.3.

Answer (score 4):

Apple makes notes about this for every revision.  You can find them all [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)